# Platform event API name imported in LWC uses "c" instead of "e" as suffix?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, second-generation-packaging

I'm trying to make a component in a managed package to subscribe to a certain platform event, and referencing the channel with its API name previously worked:

```js
import BATCH_EVENT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/BatchExportEvent__e'

subscribe('/event/BatchExportEvent__e', -1, eventCallback).then(response => {
       component.subscribed = true
       component.subscription = response
})
```

But trying to use `${BATCH_EVENT_NAME.objectApiName}` to subscribe "dynamically" to the event, doesn't work. The framework returns a `BatchExportEvent__c` string (note the `c` suffix, instead of the `e`, for events).

Hardcoding the `BatchExportEvent__e` to the subscription seems to solve the issue in a development environment. However, I need to access the event's fields as well. So of course I tried to add those fields using the import syntax as well. For example:

```js
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/BatchExportEvent__e.Status__c'
```

And, again, development went smoothly. But when trying to install a package version in a development environment, I get the error:

```
exportData: Invalid reference BatchExportEvent__c.JobItemsProcessed__c
of type sobjectClass in file exportData.js
```

Notice, once more, the issue with the suffix. The platform appends `c` instead of `e`. I'm not even sure if this is the issue here anymore.

Is there a guide on how to use platform events within managed packages, and accessing them in the component?

---

Like mentioned in the comments, if I try to add the namespace manually I get the following message while pushing the code to the scratch org:

```
force-app/main/frontend/lwc/exportData/exportData.js  LWC1504:
Invalid module id "x__BatchExportEvent__e.x__AsyncApexJobId__c"
for type "schema". Explicit use of namespace "x" in file 
"exportData.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.
```

Comment: Would adding your namespace to the object and field name be any helpful? `import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/namespace__BatchExportEvent__e.namespace__Status__c`

Comment: If I remember correctly the platform doesn’t allow me to save it if I specify the namespace. I only got the error for apex classes though, so I need to check this with objects and platform events.

Comment: I've updated the question with what happens when I attempt to add the namespace explicitly, @Raul.

Comment: Oh damn, and does it allow us to use namespace `c__`?

Comment: It is not possible to specify a `c__` namespace. It doesn't exist. You would get an "invalid reference of type" error.

Comment: I would love to hear from someone at SF or otherwise knowledgeable on this topic. It seems to be a pretty basic problem. I want to write/test my code so it works both in a dev (non-namespaced) org and a packaged (namespaced) org. I can't hardwire the channel name because it is different depending on whether or not I am in a namespaced org or not. How do I even determine, from an LWC, whether I am in a namespaced org or not? Our hacky solution is to listen to both events, or to have the server send us the event name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just heard from SF...
The point is that the only suffix supported in LWC is '__c' so far.
It is not yet documented in Importing Limitations section here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about.
Importing Platform Events (with '__e' suffix) should soon be added as a part of Importing Limitations sections into this doc.
Hopefully, it will be supported in one of future releases.

So, it is not a limitation applied to a managed package. It is a general LWC limitation. If you try to deploy a LWC with '__e' suffix with Metadata API to any org, the suffix would be replaced with '__c' it the target org because of this limitation.

Comment: That's good to know. This is not a known issue then, but comes from an internal response from a case, right? Would you be willing to update this question with more information regarding what they responded to you?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira that is correct, it comes from a case. I opened it to force them create a known issue, but it appeared to be a Doc bug according to their answer.